# change css polymer element

Tags: css, polymer

I am using the `paper-input` and I have a pattern with a error-mesage

```html
<paper-input label="Horas" name="hours" auto-validate required pattern="([0]:[0-5][0-9])|([1-9]|[1][0-9]|2[0-3])(:[0-5][0-9])?" error-message="Formato de las horas inválido"></paper-input>
```

When you write in the `paper-input` and the hour is not correct the error-mesage is visible. This error-message is red by default, this error-message is used by `paper-input-container/error` and is red.

I want change this color of the `paper-input`, if I change in the html of the element it works, but I want to have the CSS style in other css outside, for example in `custom-style-paper-input-error.html` and `custom-style-paper-input-container.html`.

I want overwrite the css of `paper-input` with my `css-custom`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `custom-style-paper-input-error.html`, add a `style[is=custom-style]` element and inside it write this

```
:root {
  --paper-input-container-invalid-color: violet;
}
```

if you want it applied for all paper-inputs. Otherwise, you can use [shared-styles](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#style-modules).

Comment: i added the var() to shared-styles

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to set the style for the error container is to use the Polymer Styling variable from `paper-input-container`. You can lookup these variables from [its documentation page](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?active=paper-input-container#styling).

```
<style>
  :host {
    --paper-input-container-invalid-color: #ff0000;
  }
</style>
```

To externalize that style you'll want to create what Polymer calls a [style module](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#style-modules) and add your style in there. For example:

```
<!-- custom-style-paper-input-error.html -->
<dom-module id="custom-style-paper-input-error">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        --paper-input-container-invalid-color: #ff0000;
      }
    </style> 
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Then where you'd like to use it, you use an HTML import to import that file like you would any other Polymer element, and then "include" it in your style of your element like this:

```
<style include="custom-style-paper-input-error"></style>
```

You can of course change the name of that as long as it matches the `id` of the `dom-module` in your external file.